# HTML 5 history api only work from index page

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, twitter-bootstrap

i have this html index page, the problem is that the history api (to load only the wanted .jsp inside a div and change uri) only works from the index page, if i do a refresh or a enter in the uri, it only display the desired .jsp and not the menu anymore:

ps: im using MVC (VRaptor)

index.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>

    <!-- font-awesome icons -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- Bootstrap -->

    <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>

  <div style="width:100%;"> 
<div id="menu" style="float:left; width:20%;">
</div>
<div id="header" class="well">Bem vindo<b> ${userLogado.nome }</b></div>
<div id="conteudo" style="float:right; width:80%; ">
</div>

</div>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/menuLoad.js"></script> 

  </body>
</html>
```

the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#menu").load("/restrict/menu");        
    });

$('a').click(function() {
    pageurl = $(this).attr('href');
    if(pageurl!=window.location){
        window.history.pushState({path:pageurl},'',pageurl);
        }
     $('#conteudo').load($(this).attr('href'), function(responseText, statusText, xhr)
                {

         if(xhr.status == 403) { 
             $('#conteudo').load("/error/error403");

         }
         if(xhr.status == 404) { 
             $('#conteudo').load("/error/error404");

         }
         if(xhr.status == 405) { 
             $('#conteudo').load("/error/error405");

         }

         /*
         if(statusText == "success")
                 alert("Successfully loaded the content!");
         if(statusText == "error")
                 alert("An error occurred: " + xhr.status + " - " + xhr.statusText);
                 */
 });

      return false;
    });
```

so every  call this JS and than load the href inside the #conteudo, but i enter directly in uri /restrict/menu it only display the unformatted bootstrap menu, since the  bootstrap.js, bootstrap.css for bootstap is in the index.jsp and not in the menu.jsp, there is another solution for cases when the user do a refresh to not just display the desired .jsp, but also the index.jsp, but showing the writted link inside the #conteudo?

sorry if im not clear

Answer (score 0):

History API allows user to manipulate the contents of history stack by clicking "back" or "next" button. Url will be replaced with new one, but won't cause the browser to load the document from new url. It just push the state object to stack and then change the URL.

Seems like you're using PJAX technique to load partial content asynchronously instead of loading whole page. Entering uri or refreshing page will send a request to server and browser will load a new page. So you have to identify the type of request in the backend - returning partial content if it's a "PJAX" request or returning full page if it's a normal request.

For example, I assume that your web structure looks like this:

```
/index
------/about
------/experience
------/contact
```

And you want to load partial content of these three link asynchronously when user click the links on the main page even if user visit the page by entering /index/about url.

**Step 1: Add a custom header "X-PJAX" which makes backend can identify the type of the request**

```
pageurl = $(this).attr('href');
$.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('href'),
    dataType: "html",
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-PJAX', 'true')
    },
    success: function(response){
        $('#conteudo').empty().append(response);
        history.pushState({path:pageurl},'',pageurl)
    }
});
```

**Step 2: Identify the request type and return the proper response in the backend**

```
if(header contains X-PJAX header){
    //return partial content
}else{
    //return full page
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have find a solution to your problem. 
But may anyone who has same problem may be helpful from my answer.

I had a similar problem and this is how I fixed it. I have taken reference from http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

You need to change the URL using this line of code inside your function which is used to load the content

```
     history.pushState(null,null,strURL);
```

Then use this to handle back and forward browser navigation button clicks

```
  function navigate(href) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", "YOUR URL"+href.split("/").pop(),false); 
    req.send(null);
    if (req.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = req.responseText;
      $("#div").load(" #div").hide().fadeIn(1000);
      return true;
     }
    return false;
   }

 window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
 navigate(location.pathname);});
 e.preventDefault();
 }
```